# Convert JSON to CSV in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, csv

Is there any already available library that can convert JSON string (most probably more than 1 rows of data) to CSV file.

I googled a lot for any such libraries in Scala, but I could find none.

What I am required to do is retrieve Data from a DB source, the result-set are in JSON format, and convert them into CSV.

Before what I did was converted the JSON into relevant Seq[case-class] and tried to used libraries like:

- [Scala-csv (tototoshi)](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv)
- [Might-csv](https://github.com/t-pleasure/mighty-csv)

But these didn't prove much useful when in case of case class containing deep hierarchies.

Any Suggestions??

Comment: What do you expect such a library to do? Considering that JSON and CSV represent two very different data structures (CSV is a simple two-dimensional table, while JSON uses complex tree and list structures) I doubt very much that there is any way to have a finished library that can do that automatically. What concrete problems do you have? How does your JSON structure look like and how so you what the CSV to look like?

Comment: Like I have said using JSON was only a solution I came up with, wasn't saying if this was the more appropriate, check this site=> http://konklone.io/json/ OpenCsv, SuperCsv just hoping if there are scala port of these popular java-csv libraries. But,my main requirement is converting List/Seq of objects to CSV, which the above mentioned libraries do properly. Was just looking for scala based libraries.

Comment: Why can't Scala use the "popular java-csv libraries"?

Comment: Of course they can, was asking the community if there are java ports of these libs or better if there are mature scala libs

Answer (score 0):

[product-collections](https://github.com.marklister/product-collections) will convert a Seq[case class] to csv.

```
case class Foo(a:Int,b:String)
Seq(Foo(1,"aa"),Foo(2,"bb")).csvIterator.mkString("\n")
res27: String =
1,"aa"
2,"bb"
```

To deserialize json I'd probably use scala pickling.

"Deep hierarchies" are likely to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by deep hierarchies. Something like this?

```
case class Baz(i: Int)
case class Bar(baz: Baz)
case class Foo(bar: Bar)
```

In which case [kantan.csv](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv) can answer part of the equation: turning deep case class hierarchies into CSV data. It's fairly trivial, provided you don't mind a shapeless dependency:

```
import kantan.csv.ops._
import kantan.csv.generic.codecs._

val fs: List[Foo] = ???

fs.foldLeft(new File("output.csv").asCsvWriter[Foo])(_ write _).close
```

If you have an issue with shapeless, you can provide encoders for your case classes yourself:

```
import kantan.csv._

implicit val bazCodec = Codec.caseCodec1(Baz.apply, Baz.unapply)(0)
implicit val barCodec = Codec.caseCodec1(Bar.apply, Bar.unapply)(0)
implicit val fooCodec = Codec.caseCodec1(Foo.apply, Foo.unapply)(0)
```

A bit more boilerplatey, but still acceptable, I think.